# How to call Spark UDF on Datasets of case classes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a simple case class:

```
case class Geometry(id: Int, multiPolygon: MultiPolygon)
```

The `MultiPolygon` **is also a case class**:

```
case class Pt(x: Double, y: Double)
case class Polygon(outer: List[Pt], inner: List[List[Pt]])
case class MultiPolygon(polygons: List[Polygon]) {
    def area(): Double = ...
}
```

I'm trying to call the `area` function as UDF, so **not** via something like `.map(g => (g.id, g.multiPolygon.area))`, that deserializes the whole `Geometry` object back in JVM memory.

As I need to use this function in **SQL**, I registered a UDF:

```
session.udf.register[Double, MultiPolygon]("my_area", { mp: MultiPolygon => mp.area })
```

The test Dataset is a `Dataset[Geometry]`, registed as `geometries`. Good. Then problem is that, when I try to do something like:

```
SELECT id, my_area(multiPolygon) FROM geometries
```

I get an exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$19: (struct<polygons:array<struct<outer:array<struct<x:double,y:double>>,inner:array<array<struct<x:double,y:double>>>>>>) => double)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to Polygons
```

The schema of the Dataset is:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- multiPolygon: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- polygons: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- outer: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- inner: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = false)
```

The same exception is thrown with Dataset interface:

```
val areaUDF = udf[Double, MultiPolygon](_.area)
val area = geometries.withColumn("areas", areaUDF('multiPolygon))
```

Although the outer Dataset is correctly defined as `Dataset[Geometry]`, not just as `DataFrame`, and the UDF has input parameter of type `MultiPolygon`, Spark SQL tries to **cast** the structure object attached to the field named `multiPolygon` to `MultiPolygon`, failing.

Instead, it should **deserialize** the `MultiPolygon` back to its JVM object representation from the struct, the only type the UDF can digest, using the same mechanism used for `.select(...).as[MultiPolygon].collect()`.

It seems that the Dataset interface *simplifies* the case classes to a melange of native types, structs and arrays, without retaining the class names, and there isn't an easy way back. It seems it's not always possible to deserialize a compatible structure back to a case class or, at least, when it should happen automatically, it doesn't always happen.

Comment: why do you want to use an UDF instead of `map`? I you already have a Dataset, UDF does not make sense in my opinion.

Comment: I'm testing more the limits of Datasets, DataFrames, SQL, an their interoperability. I'd like to use custom functions in SQL and these should work on entire rows but also single columns. I can call `map` on the entire row, `Geometry` in this case, but this would lead to the deserialization of the whole object. If I need to call it instead on just one of its fields, `multiPolygon` of type `MultiPolygon`, only that field would be deserialized (I assume). I wanted to test the boundaries.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by avoiding `Dataset.map`? You mention deserializing whole JVM objects, but this is not really what Spark does with `Dataset`. As of Spark 2.0, `DataFrame` is actually just `Dataset[Row]`, the way these are stored internally is basically the same. `Dataset[T]` uses `Encoder[T]` to represent the internal object data of type `T` in a columnar format precisely so it doesn't have to do full serialization/deserialization in the way it has to with a generic `RDD[T]`. It's also why there is currently only built in support for product types.

Comment: @kapunga, forget `Dataset.map` and why I want to avoid it (already answered question: to test the boundaries). Assume I need to call that function in SQL (that is a valid assumption).

Comment: You can't call a class method in SQL, SQL doesn't have support for arbitrary complex data types. The data types SQL can handle are things that you could find in a hive table for example. You can switch between the SQL API and the `Dataset` API between operations, but accessing a complex type like `Multipolygon` from SQL is something you can't do because they are separate abstractions and you can't mix the two. In short, if you want to be able to access class methods etc. that operate on complex datatypes (like `Multipolygon`) you have to use the `Dataset` API and functions like `.map`.

Comment: I'm not trying to call a class method. I'm trying to call a function that takes `MultiPolygon` as input. The fact that that function calls a class method is an implementation detail. It almost works, just that the object passed to the function is a complex `struct` instead of `MultiPolygon' . I say that that `struct` should be converted to `MultiPolygon` before being passed, the some way it's converted to a case class `X` in the code `myDataframe.as[X].collect()`, that return `List[X]` and not `List[struct]`.